# Quartzscheduler run on 1st and 3rd Monday of the month

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'd like to run a job every first and third Monday of the month. I'm using a CronTriggerBean that I'm trying to configure with the following expressions but i doesn't work:

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 ? * MON#1,3 *" />
```

or

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 ? * MON#1,MON#3 *" />
```

The first expression only runs the job on the first Monday while the second one runs the job on the third Monday.

Is there any way I could achieve this with a CronTriggerBean? I'm using quartz-1.6.5 with XML config so I don't think I could configure a SimpleTriggerBean to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with a single trigger bean. You will need to create 2 separate and register them with the scheduler:

```
<bean id="cronTriggerJobFirstMonday"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="YourQuartzJobBean" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 ? * MON#1 *" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronTriggerJobThirdMonday"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="yourQuartzJobBean" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 ? * MON#3 *" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerJobFirstMonday" />
            <ref bean="cronTriggerJobThirdMonday" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you configure two Quartz-cron jobs triggering same module ?

First Monday of every month -   0 0 12 ? 1/1 MON#1 *

Second Monday of every month -  0 0 12 ? 1/1 MON#2 *

- hope this will simplify your solution.